# Reuse Ionic2 components into my angular2 desktop version

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm going to start a Ionic2 application, but I wloud like to re-use my components for the future angular2 desktop version of my website.

Because they have a different syntax ( for example the @Page decorator ) I don't think that's possible.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could try to add both `@Component()` and `@Page()` decorators. Neither shouldn't choke on the decorator it doesn't care about.